# Detect if Android RecyclerView which is taller than screen height has reached end

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to load more items when my RecyclerView reaches the last item, and everything works fine with RecyclerViews that fit the screen, but when it's bigger than the screen size(some other view is on top of it or below it or something) things go wrong and it's always returning its last item as the last `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` any ideas?

This code works fine with recylerviews who are matching the screen height:

```
container = (RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.container);
    //container.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(10));
    final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(base);
    container.setLayoutManager(llm);
    container.setHasFixedSize(true);
    container.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if( loading || allLoaded || llm.findLastVisibleItemPosition() < recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1)
                return;
            bottomLoadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            offset += limit;
            new PostLoader(base).execute("");
        }
    });
```

but it wont work when reclycerview is not matching screen height for example with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <behzad.bases.views.MyViewPager
                android:id="@+id/my_slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

                    <include
                        layout="@layout/loading_view"/>

                    <include
                        layout="@layout/loading_bottom_view"/>

                </FrameLayout>   

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

simplifed version of xml:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
<AppBarLayout & Collpasing>
    <!-- some content with fixed height-->
</AppBarLayout & Collpasing>
<container>
    <reclyerview>
</container>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is that, with this layout, I'm always getting the last item in `llm.findLastVisibleItemPosition()`, which is making my `if` meaningless and constantly calling `LoadMore` until `allLoaded` is true.

How can I fix this? I think I should replace `llm.findLastVisibleItemPosition()` with something else in this case, but don't know what.

Comment: I suspect it's the NestedScrollView that's causing problems here. Why do you need it in the first place?

Comment: i need it for the swipe refresh layout ..it doesn't work properly if i dont put it there :( 
i've seen some people using a Adapter class which can contain both their normal items and their slider as first item of recyclerview in internet...but i'd like to avoid that if possible.